# How to dynamically inject REST API params?

Tags: node.js, express, microsoft-graph-api, node-modules

I am working on nodejs project where I need to make several ms graph api calls to get some data. Some example calls are as follows

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/manager
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userPrincipalName}/notebooks
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/photo/
```

My goal was to not use request module every time to call above 3 apis and get data separately. I wanted to create some sort if helper function where I can pass in what URL i need to use and what is {userPrincipalName}

so i created graphendpoints.js to store all the url's

```
module.exports = {
    manager: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userPrincipalName/manager',
    notebooks: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userPrincipalName}/notebooks',
photo: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/photo/'
  };
```

this is how I make call to graph by single function by auth token & url. I didn't to have each separate method to execute request for manager,notebooks,or photo etc.

```
executeGraphApi: function (token, url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let parsedBody = []
            request.get({
                    url: url,
                    headers: {
                        authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
                    }
                },
                function (err, response, body) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                    } else {
                        parsedBody.push(JSON.parse(body).displayName)
                        resolve(parsedBody)
                    }
                })
        });
    }
```

helper function runMSGraphApi(url) to call above executeGraphApi(token,url)

```
var graphcallrunner = require('../../app/msgraph/graphcallrunner');
runMSGraphApi: function (url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
            msGraph.getAccessToken()
                .then(function (token) {
                    graphcallrunner.executeGraphApi(token,url)
                        .then(function (results) {
                            resolve(results)
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            reject(error)
                        })
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error)
                })
        })
    }
```

Consumer of this looks like as follows. I needed to make sure whoever wants to make a call to ms graph just use runMSGraphApi() and pass in correct url.

```
var graphendpoints = require('../../../msgraph/graphendpoints.js');
graphapihelper.runMSGraphApi(graphendpoints.manager),
```

If you see above I selected manager api call from graphendpoints.js and passed in that url. This url is actually 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/manager

where {userPrincipalName} is not injected. How can I pass the value of  {userPrincipalName} dynamically to so final url construction in executeGraphApi() looks like.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/bob.bar@google.com/manager
```

Comment: Why not use the Microsoft Graph JavaScript SDK? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to do so

```js
const endpoints = {
  manager: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userPrincipalName/manager',
  notebooks: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userPrincipalName}/notebooks',
  photo: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/photo/'
}

function parseUrl(url, params) {
  let result = url
  const regex = /(?<={)(.*)(?=})/
  const match = url.match(regex)

  if (match) {
    const replace = match[0]
    const value = params[replace]
    const holeThing = /{(?<={)(.*)(?=})}/
    if (value) {
      result = result.replace(holeThing, value);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Please specify the value for parsing the URL')
    }
  }
  return result
}

const url = parseUrl(endpoints.notebooks, {
  userPrincipalName: 'woof'
})

console.log(url)
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. When consumer tried to use it like follows where graphendpoints.manager will be field with 

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/manager

`graphapihelper.runMSGraphApi(graphendpoints.manager),
`

i would need way to pass in or fill in {userPrincipalName} with bob.bar@google.com on the fly.